# Custom directive won't react to attribute changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I'm currently building a modal directive that I can use to populate with some data tables.  I have an attribute on the directive called modal-visible that will be a boolean value, defaulting at false.  If the default is true, on load, the modal is visible.  However, when I initially set it to false and change the value from an event, the attribute changes, but the directive does not pick the change up.  I have a watch in the link portion of the directive, but that only picks up the initial change.

Below is my code examples.  I just have a simple test page with a button and the modal.  The modal attribute modal-visible is set to 'false'.  When the button is clicked, the modal's modal-visible attribute is updated to 'true', but the modal does not show on the page.  Can someone please guide me to this solution and also give me a good explination on why this is happening?  Thanks.

testing.html

```
<button id="btn1" class="btn btn-default">Click Me</button>
<modal id="chartModal" modal-title="Testing a Modal" modal-visible="false">
  <p>Body</p>
</modal>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var modal = $("#chartModal");
    var btn = $("#btn1");

    btn.on("click", function() {
        modal.attr("modal-visible", "true");
    })
</script>
```

modal.js

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module("contactAuthApp");


//////////////////////////
//  BEGIN - DIRECTIVES
//////////////////////////

    var modalDirective = function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                modalVisible: "=",
                modalTitle: "@"
            },
            transclude: true,
            controller: function($scope) {

            },
            templateUrl: "utils/modal.html",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                //Attach base classes
                element.addClass("modal fade");

                //Hide or show the modal
                scope.showModal = function (visible) {
                    if (visible) {
                        element.modal("show");
                    } else {
                        element.modal("hide");
                    }
                }

                //Check to see if the modal-visible attribute exists
                if (!attrs.modalVisible) {

                    //The attribute isn't defined, show the modal by default
                    scope.showModal(true);

                } else {

                    //Watch for changes to the modal-visible attribute
                    scope.$watch("modalVisible", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                        scope.showModal(newValue);
                    });

                    //Update the visible value when the dialog is closed through UI actions (Ok, cancel, etc.)
                    element.bind("hide.bs.modal", function () {
                        scope.modalVisible = false;
                        if (!scope.$$phase && !scope.$root.$$phase)
                            scope.$apply();
                    });

                }
            }
        };
    }

//////////////////////////
//  END - DIRECTIVES
//////////////////////////  


    app.directive("modal", modalDirective);

})();
```

modal.html (directive template)

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div data-ng-transclude></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDITED**

Hey runTarm: here is my updated code changing the isolate scope of modalVisible to '@' and observing the attribute in link.  Still can't get it to work:

```
var modalDirective = function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            modalVisible: "@",
            modalTitle: "@"
        },
        transclude: true,
        controller: function($scope) {

        },
        templateUrl: "utils/modal.html",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            //Attach base classes
            element.addClass("modal fade");

            //Hide or show the modal
            scope.showModal = function (visible) {
                if (visible === true) {
                    element.modal("show");
                } else {
                    element.modal("hide");
                }
            }

            //Watch for changes to the modal-visible attribute
            attrs.$observe("modalVisible", function (val) {
                console.log(val);
                scope.showModal(val);
            });

            //Update the visible value when the dialog is closed through UI actions (Ok, cancel, etc.)
            element.bind("hide.bs.modal", function () {
                scope.modalVisible = false;
                if (!scope.$$phase && !scope.$root.$$phase)
                    scope.$apply();
            });

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two-way binding between a directive's isolated scope and a parent scope cannot be used with a constant like that.

```
<modal modal-visible="false"> // false is a constant boolean value not a variable in the parent scope
```

You have to choose between keep using the two-way binding or use a custom watch function to detect the attribute changes.

Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/ZwrL6qlKTQCWZJ3EsXdM?p=preview for examples.

In the plunker above, `modal-two` is using the two-way binding:

```
<button id="btn2" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isModalVisible = true">Click Me v2</button>
<modal-two id="chartModal2" modal-title="Testing a Modal" modal-visible="isModalVisible">
  <p>Body</p>
</modal-two>
```

and `modal` is using the custom watch function:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
  return element.attr('modal-visible');
}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
  scope.showModal(newValue === 'true');
});
```

However, I would discorage the use of the custom watch function, it isn't an angular way to do it and might cause a performance issue.

Comment: Awesome!  I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, the `$attr.$observe()` cannot be used in this case. You could use a custom watch function to detect the attribute change but I don't recommend it. Please see the modal-two example in the plunker instead.

Comment: Going with the two way binding, could I also just create the controller within the directive or does it have to be outside of it?

Comment: It have to be outside as an application controller. The directive's controller is a different thing and serve a different purpose.

Comment: Gotcha....so is there a way to do this outside of an app controller and in the directive?  The reason being is that the modal directive will need to be called within other specified element controllers

Comment: I'm not sure what you means, but you could use a indirect two-way binding like `other directive <=> app controller <=> modal directive`.  An another approach is to not using the `modal-visible` attribute at all, then using another mechanism to communicate between two directive such as injecting the same service or `$scope.$broadcast()` and `$scope.$on()`.

Comment: Here's what I mean:  I route a user to dashboard.html, in which I have a dashboard directive that displays multiple charts. This page is using the DashboardController as well as the dashboard directives.  Each dashboard directive will contain multiple chart directives.  With the chart directive, there are clickable data points.  If a data point is clicked, I need the modal to show up and display a table using data from the chart directive.  Make sense?  The modal needs to be on the dashboard.html page. Sorry for the complexity.

Comment: If that the case, I would go with the `$broadcast()/$on()` or a shared service approach.

Answer (score 2):

You have the watch in else block for this condition `!attrs.modalVisible`, hence it gets triggered on fail of that condition. Modify the directive (removing the if-else block) to something like below:

```
//Watch for changes to the modal-visible attribute
scope.$watch("modalVisible", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if( newValue ) {
        scope.showModal(newValue);
    } else {
        //Update the visible value when the dialog is closed 
        //through UI actions (Ok, cancel, etc.)
        element.bind("hide.bs.modal", function () {
            scope.modalVisible = false;
            if (!scope.$$phase && !scope.$root.$$phase)
                scope.$apply();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried taking out the if-else block and replace it with your code, still is not working.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Note one simple thing: Since the isolated scope variable is two-way bound, it can be changed from parent scope of directive. Therefore, you are watching it. Every time the watch is triggered the possible values of the variable is null, undefined, true, false. Now you apply your own logic whatever you need inside the watch for all those possible scenarios. makes sense? :)

Comment: since event is happening outside of angular might be better to to use `attrs.$observe` instead of `scope.$watch`. Personally I think it is smarter to get rid of the jQuery and do this all internally within angular

Comment: Sort of.  In this case, what would be the parent scope?  If I created a controller for the directive, will that be the parent?  Also, the code you posted above doesn't solve the problem.  When I load the page, and console log in the $watch, it picks up the value.  When I click the button, the attribute changes and the $watch doesn't pick that up for some reason.